# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: HP Officejet 3830 doesn't connect

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, hp, hplip

My family and I just moved. We don't have access to internet outside of our phone's mobile hotspots. This printer has a history of refusing to print, but previously it *usually* only took a very long time to start printing (with Linux Mint, and cable internet).

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS now, and I installed hplip (3.22.6) yesterday, and I was able to print a test page, despite being given some warnings and errors. However, today I can't get it to print anything. I have run `hp-doctor`, `hp-upgrade`, and `hp-check`, tried connecting the printer and/or my computer to my mother's phone's mobile hotspot, and my own phone's hotspot, reinstalled hplip and restarted. It keeps refusing to print, citing "communication error". My mom has been able to get it to print when the printer's connected to her phone's hotspot, with a laptop that runs Windows 10.

`hp-doctor` complains about being unable to connect to the HPLIP site (code 8), warns that it failed to read the ppd files for both the printer and fax of my printer, and complains of being unable to communicate with them (code 12). I am not sure how to fix any of this.

How can I get my HP Officejet 3830 to work?

```
luminous_nutria@Alita:~$ hp-doctor
/usr/share/hplip/check.py:685: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if 'getfacl' not in g and '' is not g and 'file' not in g:

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.22.6)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.


HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.22.6)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

 

Checking for Deprecated items....
No Deprecated items are found


Checking for HPLIP updates....

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.22.6)
HPLIP upgrade latest version ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

error: Failed to connect to HPLIP site. Error code = 8
error: Failed to connect to HPLIP site. Error code = 8
error: Failed to get latest version of HPLIP.
error: Failed to upgrade latest HPLIP. Is hp-upgrade already running (i.e. foreground or background)?


Checking for Dependencies....

---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 13 13:09:46 UTC 2022 GNU/Linux
 Host: Alita
 Proc: 5.15.0-52-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 13 13:09:46 UTC 2022 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: 12 20.04
 Bitness: 64 bit


-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.22.6
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is supported for ubuntu distro  20.04 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.22.6

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.22.6
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.22.6
icon=/usr/share/applications
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv/hp
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=no
foomatic-drv-install=no
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.22.6
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt5
qt3=no
qt4=no
qt5=yes
policy-kit=no
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=yes
class-driver=no


Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
Plugins are not installed. Could not access file: No such file or directory

Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[upgrade]
notify_upgrade = true
last_upgraded_time = 1666799189
pending_upgrade_time = 0

[installation]
date_time = 10/26/22 11:12:34
version = 3.22.6


 <Package-name>        <Package-Desc>      <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status>   <Comment>

-------------------------
| External Dependencies |
-------------------------

 cups                 CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             2.3.1           OK         'CUPS Scheduler is running'
 gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.50            OK         -
 xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.29          OK         -
 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.12.16         OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.20.3          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.7             OK         -

------------------------
| General Dependencies |
------------------------

 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               2.3.1           OK         -
 cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               2.3.1           OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               b'2.31'         OK         -
 libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 libavahi-dev         libavahi-dev                                                 REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.8             OK         -
 libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.1.1           OK         -
 python3X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.10          OK         -
 python3-notify2      Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 python3-pyqt5-dbus   PyQt 5 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt5                         OPTIONAL        5.0             5.14.1          OK         -
 python3-pyqt5        PyQt 5- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        5.0             5.14.1          OK         -
 python3-dbus         Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.16          OK         -
 python3-xml          Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.2.9           OK         -
 python3-devel        Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.10          OK         -
 python3-pil          PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               9.2.0           OK         -
 python3-reportlab    Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.6.11          OK         -

--------------
| COMPILEDEP |
--------------

 libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.6           OK         -
 gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               9.4.0           OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.2.1           OK         -

---------------------
| Python Extentions |
---------------------

 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.22.6          OK         -
 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.22.6          OK         -

----------------------
| Scan Configuration |
----------------------

 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.22.6          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'
 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.22.6          OK         -

------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

device `hpaio:/net/OfficeJet_3830_series?zc=HPC8D9D243403D' is a Hewlett-Packard OfficeJet_3830_series all-in-one


--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

No devices found.

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------

 
OfficeJet_3830
--------------
Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/net/OfficeJet_3830_series?zc=HPC8D9D243403D
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/OfficeJet_3830.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/OfficeJet_3830.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: printer OfficeJet_3830 is idle.  enabled since Wed 26 Oct 2022 11:09:28 AM CDT
error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hp:/net/OfficeJet_3830_series?zc=HPC8D9D243403D
error: unable to open channel
error: Communication status: Failed

OfficeJet_3830_fax
------------------
Type: Fax
Device URI: hpfax:/net/OfficeJet_3830_series?zc=HPC8D9D243403D
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/OfficeJet_3830_fax.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/OfficeJet_3830_fax.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: printer OfficeJet_3830_fax is idle.  enabled since Tue 25 Oct 2022 11:40:28 AM CDT
error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hpfax:/net/OfficeJet_3830_series?zc=HPC8D9D243403D
error: unable to open channel
error: Communication status: Failed


--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

 

Checking Permissions....


Checking for Configured Queues....
warning: Fail to read ppd=/etc/cups/ppd/OfficeJet_3830.ppd file
warning: Insufficient permission to access file /etc/cups/ppd/OfficeJet_3830.ppd
warning: Could not complete Queue(s) configuration check


Checking for HP Properitery Plugin's....
No plug-in printers are configured.
 

Checking for Printer Status....
error: 'OfficeJet_3830' Printer is either Powered-OFF or Failed to communicate.
Turn On Printer and re-run hp-doctor
error: 'OfficeJet_3830_fax' Printer is either Powered-OFF or Failed to communicate.
Turn On Printer and re-run hp-doctor

Diagnose completed...



More information on Troubleshooting,How-To's and Support is available on http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html
```

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstalling the printer (remove it as a device, then add it again)? I had similar issues with HP printers working on-and-off with Ubuntu, that seemed to temporarily fix things sometimes. Maybe someone has a more-permanent solution

Comment: @Esther It works! Thank you!